# Responsive breakpoint breaks incorrect

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with a landingpage that I am building. When the page hits the breakpoint: 991px, the book picture is dipasering under the banner.

Is there someone who can help me solve this, and see through the developer tools if it is something to do with the CSS?

[Link to page.](https://inovo.dk/vidensbank/inbound-marketing-trin-for-trin/)

The Html I have is here:

```
<div class="background-image" @Html.Raw(topImageStyling)>
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 img logo img-responsive">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="book container col-sm-12 hidden-sm hidden-xs col-md-3 col-lg-4">
                    <img src="
                </div>

                    <div class="container col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-8">

                        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerText))
            {
                if (pageAlias == "Blog")
                {
                                <h1 class="header-xl center">
                                    @Html.Raw(headerText)
                                </h1>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <p class="header-xl center">
                                    @Html.Raw(headerText)
                                </p>
                            }
                        }
                        @if (CurrentPage.HasValue("imageTeaserText"))
            {
                            <p class="sub-header center">
                                @Html.Raw(CurrentPage.imageTeaserText)
                            </p>
                        }


                    </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 visible-sm visible-xs">
                    <img src="
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 main-content" id="main-content">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("inovoGrid")
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a `.hidden-sm` on your `div.book.container`. This class will make the book dissapear on 991px to 768px

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That dosent seem to be the problem. I just tried to delete that, but still the same

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of this ?

Comment: Are you asking why part of the book is hidden when it is under the title _INBOUND MARKETING - TRIN FOR TRIN_?

Comment: yes excatly @hungerstar. The reason why some tag is hidden /visible, is that I would like that logo, book picture and headline where horizontal on xs instead of vertical. But appartly it did not work?

Comment: Remove `min-height` from `.background-image`?

Comment: When I removed the min-height the banner disappeared. I delelet the max height, and it actually works when the screen is getting smaller. But there is 2 breakpoints it os jumping around. But can we maybe use that for something?

Comment: @NeKr you must have changed something. Remove 'min-height` and `max-height` and add `overflow: hidden;` to `.background-image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In landingpage.css line number 804 `position: relative;` invisible it.
Solve if we put another class in 
`<div class="col-sm-12 visible-sm visible-xs new-class"> .... </div>`

.new-class {
position:inherit !important
}

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sorry I did not get that. Could you maybe explain again?

Comment: Because of position:relative the book image invisible. so i just put a new class in book div and change relative to inherit and makes it !important so it will show the book image.

Comment: ok thank you. Is it possible you would ctrl + k  the code, so I can see it?

Comment: @FaisalKhanSamrat if you visit the OP's link, I think he's looking to make the book image with the green border fully visible. If your solution is targeting the `<div>` wrapping that image, then your solution does not work.

Comment: @hungerstar please inspect the link and see the line number 804 in landingcss.css change the position in inherit the border and the image both are visible.

Comment: @FaisalKhanSamrat I have done so. When you do that you're overflowing the containing element (blue background) which may not be the desired outcome. Especially on smaller screen sizes where the book image overlaps text. You're also modify core Bootstrap classes globally which may have unintended consequences elsewhere.